# Why don't standard containers like std::vector implement interfaces?

Tags: c++

I want to store a vector of queues.

The queues may have different template types therefore I cannot store them in the same vector.

```
std::queue<int> aQueue1
std::queue<std::string> aQueue2
std::queue<float> aQueue3
std::vector<std::queue> aVec // Doesn't work because std::queue needs template arguments
```

I can store pointers to the queues in the vector however the queues do not all implement the same base class (Eg IQueue).

```
std::vector<std::IQueue*> aVec //IQueue does not exist
```

Why does this not exist? 
What are my options?

In my case, the usage is that I want to check if all the queues are empty. `myqueue.empty()`

Comment: How will you be using this queue of queues? What operations do you want to perform on the inner queues? I'm having a hard time imagining a use case for a collection of heterogeneous collections.

Comment: @AidanGallagher Or even static polymorphism, where you write code templated on the queue type.  `template <typename T> bool isQueueEmpty(const std::queue<T>& q) { return q.empty(); }`

Comment: @AidanGallagher: Then you don't need an vector of queues, you need a vector of is-empty-functions

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Rather than asking about *solution Y* — a queue of queues of different types — describe *problem X*. Why do you have queues of different types, what's in them, and what are you doing with them? There's probably a better solution if we look at the underlying problem. For example, if the queues store parallel sets of items then perhaps you'd be better off with a *single* queue that stores structs containing an `int`, a `string`, and a `float`. (That's just an example.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The part of the `std` library that you are using here -- `std::queue` -- descends from a library called "the standard template library".

In it, Alexander Stepanov worked out you could decouple container operations from the operated on data, and algorithms from the containers they operate on.  All while generating code that was close to the performance of hand-crafted C.

This was amazing.

You could do something similar with code generation utilities, but such generated code was not understandable by the compiler or debugger, at least how it connected back to the original.  The STL let every C++ user use a red-black tree with tweaked performance and bug-free implementations without even thinking much about it.

Now, one of the principles of C++ is that you don't pay for what you don't use.  When you add a virtual interface to an object, there is a bunch of overhead that is added.

First, a per-implementation-class virtual function table has to exist at runtime.  Second, RTTI is added.  Third, inlining opportunities evaporate.  Forth, the implementation objects have to carry around an extra vtable pointer.  Fifth, dispatch to methods requires extra layers of indirection.  Sixth, knock-on types like iterators get increasingly complex.

All of these costs are not carried by `std::queue<int>`.  The implementation of `std::queue<int>` is roughly what you'd get if you wrote your own custom C queue based off block-allocated double-array tables.

I mean, you probably wouldn't write that if you wanted a queue.  But if you had lots of time you might.

---

Other languages have chosen a different path.  Languages like Java and C# have almost all objects heap-allocated with inheritance and virtual tables.  Objects are actually garbage collected references to objects, and memory locality is near impossible.

The cost of this is roughly a 2x to 3x performance reduction in most tasks.  They can get around this in narrow cases by either using external libraries, or by very carefully writing code that their optimizer can remove all of the object overhead from.

For many people that 2x to 3x reduction in performance is a-ok.  After all, investment in performance is fungible, and many tasks are much easier in Java and C#.  So you can write a quicker app that hobbles along in C#/Java, then focus your work on the critical path.  Doubling the performance of code is pretty typical when you put brain-sweat into it.

C++ isn't really an OO language.  It has functional, OO and procedural ways of writing C++.

As to how you get around it?  You write your *own* queue abstraction. Off the top of my head I can think of four ways to abstract a queue.

1. You can write your own base queue class.  With its own base queue values.
2. You can write a queue of `std::variant`s, or a `std::variant` of queues.
3. You can write a queue of `std::any`.
4. You can type-erase the queue operations and build your own vtable implementation to allow polymorphic value types.

Which one is best?  It will depend on your ability to write code, the details of your problem space, and the version of C++ you are working with.

Comment: _"It has functional [..] ways of writing C++."_ Are we sure that's correct?

Comment: @asteroids yes, I can write functional-style C++.  Or, are you complaining about my grammar?  That is barely functional.

Comment: I am not aware of any functional programming paradigms in the C++ language. It is multi-paradigm but in what sense is functional one of them? It's all procedural, OO and templates, isn't it? Or are we counting "declaring functions and lambdas" as "functional"? Perhaps you could give an example of what you mean by that statement. Thanks!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings That would be a long, long elaboration.  Try the [ask question] button above, or [look here](https://www.google.com/search?q=functional+programming+in+C%2B%2B)

Comment: Okay, those things are not really functional programming, so I guess that's the answer. :)

Answer (score 6):

This is simply not how C++ is designed. If you want a `std::queue<std::queue< A few similar types >>`, then you may use `std::queue<std::queue<std::variant< types >>>`. If you want it to contain an open-ended list of widely different types, you can use `std::queue<std::queue<std::any>>`. If your types all share a common base, you could use a queue of (smart) pointers to the base class. If there is something more adventurous you have in mind, you still have more options in C++ catering those needs. I am not suggesting it, but you could even store `void*` elements in the queue and do your own type-book-keeping.

Having said that, even though these are possible, often (but probably not always) there is a much simpler solution you're missing.

Comment: Update: "I want to check if all the queues are empty. myqueue.empty()", which means he wants a `std::queue<std::function<bool>>`

Comment: Note: If the design requires a queue that can contain any data type, you probably have a mistake in the design.

Comment: @user4581301 I was about to mention that. Even though these are possible, often (but probably not always) there is a much simpler solution you're missing.

Comment: Given the problem description, I'd probably put the variant on the outside (well, in the middle), not the inside. `std::queue<std::variant<std::queue<T1>, std::queue<T2>>>` but YMMV. Depending on the use case (which we can't see) I expect my version to involve fewer "selections" if that makes sense. It also mandates a common element type for the inner collection, which seems to be what was wanted

Comment: @MooingDuck perhaps `std::queue<std::function<bool()>>` (note parentheses)? I am not sure that's what OP wants

Comment: Thanks all. @MooingDuck I have gone with your approach. It is a bit ugly on the caller's code having to write a lamda but I think it is the best approach for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

At some point in time, the powers that be decided that these containers would utilise *generic programming* paradigms, rather than *object-oriented programming* paradigms such as base classes and polymorphic inheritance.

This decision-making process would have weighed up various pros and cons. There would have been many of both, out of scope of listing here.

One of the cons, though, as you've found, is that you cannot directly do the thing you've described. However, it seems like an edge case requirement, not worth the runtime overhead of all that virtual dispatch. It is very uncommon to need to treat various "queue of *some thing*" as a single bunch of things. And, in C++, you don't pay for what you don't use.

You can get what you want another way. I'd do it like this:

```
using QueuesType = std::variant<std::queue<int>, std::queue<std::string>, std::queue<float>>;
std::queue<QueuesType> aVec;
```

*(in reality, wrapping the variant in some class type that models your "business logic")*

Notice how you no longer need to store pointers in the outer queue, so that's already one level of indirection (and unnecessary dynamic allocation) that you've annihilated.

The downside is that you'll have to specify each `queue` type you want in the definition of `QueuesType`, or switch to `std::any`. Also, there is some machinery required in your *usage* of the variant.

But your resulting code can be quite elegant and re-usable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use polymorphism if you want to:

```
struct my_interface {
    // put methods here
};

struct int_impl : my_interface {
    std::queue<int> data;
};

struct string_impl : my_interface {
    std::queue<std::string> data;
};
```

And then use a

```
std::queue<std::unique_ptr<my_interface>>
```

If that is what you want then C++ won't prevent you from doing that. However, imposing the cost of runtime polymorphism on everybody will make those that do not need it not happy. The motto of C++ is "don't pay for what you don't use", hence the java way of doing things, where everything is inherited from `Object`, is not an option. C++ rather gives you the freedom to define an interface for objects that you want to put into a `std::queue<std::unique_ptr<my_interface>>` but it wouldn't force you to implement some special interface to put something into a queue.

Note that using an interface is invasive: You cannot put an `int` into a queue that expects a certain interface without wrapping it in a class that serves no purpose other than implementing the interface. Standard containers are more generic than that. You can put anything into standard containers as long as it fulfills certain requirements. Putting something into a container never requires you to modify a type (eg to make it inherit from some interface).

PS: `empty` is a trivial example, but consider methods like `front` or `back` that return a reference to an element in the queue. What should they return? There is no obvious answer and ordinary runtime polymorphism also has no answer to that. There are solutions but not one that fits all. There are many design decision to be taken, hence C++ provides you many tools to achieve your goal (eg `std::variant`) instead of providing one ready-to-use solution that would be good for ~1% of the use cases, ok-ish for ~5% but useless for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use polymorphism in order to achieve this behavior:

```
class EmptyBase{
public:
    virtual ~EmptyBase() = default;
    virtual bool empty() const = 0;
};


template<class Queue>
class EmptyBaseTemplate : public EmptyBase{
    Queue* q_;
public:
    bool empty() const override{
        return q_->empty();
    }
    explicit EmptyBaseTemplate(Queue& q) : EmptyBase(), q_(&q){};
};

int main() {
    std::queue<int> aQueue1;
    std::queue<std::string> aQueue2;
    std::queue<float> aQueue3;
    std::vector<EmptyBase*> aVec;
    aVec.push_back(new EmptyBaseTemplate(aQueue1));
    aVec.push_back(new EmptyBaseTemplate(aQueue2));
    aVec.push_back(new EmptyBaseTemplate(aQueue3));
    for(auto& el : aVec)
        std::cout<<el->empty()<<std::endl;
}
```

KEEP IN MIND that this is absolutely not the code you should use, it's only done for for demonstration purpose

Note: this work for only small set of "pre-requisite", which must not involve different types on parameters and return types, if you want to do more advanced stuff, the `variant`-`visitor` pattern is an easier and probably better way to do it

Comment: I mean, it's a valid solution. It's exactly the "polymorphic" queue the OP asked for, implemented simply by wrapping the standard library queue. It's going to get unmanageable quite quickly if you want any non-`empty()` things, though, particularly when it comes to iterators, or really anything that deals (directly or indirectly) with the encapsulated elements' values. A variant with some visitor pattern magic is really the way to go here.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings yes, 100% yes, but for a "beginner" POV i think that it's a easier way, but also I would use Variant, because this solution only helps fi the function is indipendente to the type, so there is no parameter with different type, and also the return type... so it's very very very limited... but if it's just for "empty"... why not mention it

Comment: If _all_ you want to do is work out whether a bunch of queues are empty then there are much better ways of doing that than putting them in some heterogenous other queue to find out. The limitations should be mentioned _especially_ as a beginner won't automatically be aware.